# Does ‘the mighty’ take a verb in plural form as in “the mighty are rendered helpless”?

Tags: verbs, numbers

There was the following sentence in the article of Time magazine’s November 25 issue under the title, “John F. Kennedy's Assassination and the Conspiracy Industry.”

> “This whiplash convergence of extremes — so sudden, so horrific, such
>   enormity — makes the assassination of John F. Kennedy an almost
>   uniquely deranging event. In a matter of seconds, **the mighty are
>   rendered helpless**; the beautiful is made hideous; tranquility turns
>   turbulent; the familiar becomes alien.” 
>   http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,2157468,00.html#ixzz2khXYshkc

I was drawn to the line in which only “the mighty” is followed  by a verb in plural form – ‘are rendered,’ while all other nouns – the beautiful, tranquility, the familiar are followed by verbs in singular form.

Isn't 'the mighty' singular in number? Shouldn’t it be followed by ‘is rendered in the same way as ‘the beautiful is made hideous’ and ‘the familiar becomes alien.’?

Is there any special reasons to use a verb in plural form for ‘the mighty’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The beautiful*, *tranquility*, *the familiar* are all mass nouns—“any quantity of it is treated as an undifferentiated unit, rather than as something with discrete subsets” ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)). They may be paraphrased as *that which* or *everything which* or *all that* is beautiful, tranquil, familiar.

*The mighty*, however, refers to persons, who are individuals, ‘discrete subsets’. To cast this clause in the singular, *the mighty is rendered helpless*, would imply that only one mighty person is being spoken of. Consequently, the clause must be cast in the plural to indicate that it is *all who are mighty* which is meant.

Comment: Your choice of plurality therefore qualifies whether you refer to an entity, or a set of entities.

Comment: StoneyB. In trying to understand difference of mass nouns and collective nouns pertinent to the above question, I found commentaries of both http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun informative for furthering understanding of the difference.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I don't think *the mighty* can be treated as a **collective** noun--it is never an entity which is "spoken of as one whole" like *the nobility* or *the proletariat*. If English declined adjectives, it would be cast in the plural, like French *les puissants*, German *die Mächtigen*.

Answer (score 2):

The question of what agreement should be used with collective nouns has been covered here before.

The answer is partly dependent on personal and regional choices: in the UK, almost everyone would choose to say

> Australia were asked to follow on.

while the Australians would almost all prefer

> England was asked to follow on.

Neither usage can be said to be wrong. What is happening is that the Australians are regarding 'England' as standing for 'the England team' - ie as a cohesive unit, while the English consider 'Australia' to stand for 'the members of the Australian team' here, so use the plural verb form to indicate this.

The English treatment here is called 'notional' or 'logical' concord (or 'synesis'); this would dictate the choice of

'Accrington Stamford was founded in 1435' - here, the club is seen as a single entity.

In your case, 'the mighty' means 'those people who have the power' and with logical concord requires a plural verb; the other nouns are more mass nouns than collectives (eg 'all that is beautiful' rather than 'the beautiful people'), and take singular agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the passage in the Bible.

> 2 Samuel 1:19
>
> A gazelle lies slain on your heights, Israel. How the mighty have
>   fallen!

This is the only possibility I can see. *Mighty* here is also considered plural.